# How to delegate constructor with struct paramaters?

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11

My question is about the new C++11 feature Delegating Constructors. So I have two similar ctors in my class and I would like to simplify their implementation. The problem that they both have structures as a parameter and when I tried to delegate them, a compiler error occured:

```
error: type ‘MyClass’ is not a direct base of ‘MyClass’
```

So here is before:

```
MyClass::MyClass ( const timeval & TV ) :
      Seconds ( TV.tv_sec),
      USeconds ( TV.tv_usec ),
{
}

MyClass::MyClass ( const timespec & TS ) :
        Seconds ( TS.tv_sec),
        USeconds ( TS.tv_nsec * 1000 ),
{
}
```

After:

```
MyClass::MyClass ( const timeval & TV ) :
      MyClass ( timeval { TV.tv_sec, TV.tv_usec/1000 } )
{
}

MyClass::MyClass ( const timespec & TS ) :
        Seconds ( TS.tv_sec),
        USeconds ( TS.tv_nsec * 1000 ),
{
}
```

Does anybody know how can I call the second ctor from the first one correctly?

Comment: Aren't you delegating the `timeval` constructor to the `timeval` constructor, creating what would be an infinite recursion if allowed?

Comment: which compiler ? are you sure your compiler supports delegating ctors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the obvious error (you are trying to delegate to the same constructor) the code is correct and should work on g++4.7

```
MyClass::MyClass ( const timeval & TV ) :
      MyClass ( timespec { TV.tv_sec, TV.tv_usec/1000 } )
{
}

MyClass::MyClass ( const timespec & TS ) :
        Seconds ( TS.tv_sec),
        USeconds ( TS.tv_nsec * 1000 ),
{
}
```

It might be an issue with your compiler/version.

Comment: Just because it is obvious to you, doesn't mean it is obvious to the asker.

Comment: @Matt: It might not be apparent, but once pointed at it, I don't think that he will not consider that obvious.